# Decrease translucency of bars in iOS7?

Tags: ios7

iOS7 has translucent bars. Is it possible in XCode-ObjectiveC to make them show more of what's behind, i.e. to decrease the thickness of the translucent "glass"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it's not possible with the default navigation/tab bars. You should make your own implementation of both bars and make your own gaussian blur.